# Does this array function exist in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a PHP function that will do the following:

Move a specified array value from it's current index and then either:

1. Moved in between two existing indices.
2. Swapped with a second index/value.

I made the class below for the task, but wonder if there is a pre-existing function in the PHP library?

Here is the class I have created for the task:

```
class Rearranger
{   
    /*
     * Determines how to move the specified value.
     */
    public static function go($list, $indexToMove, $offset)
    {
        if(($offset == ($indexToMove - 1)) || ($offset == ($indexToMove + 1))) {
            //Value is only being moved up or down one index, so just swap the values
            $list = self::swap($list, $indexToMove, $offset);
        } else if($offset < $indexToMove) {
            //Value is being moved up (will be changing to a lower value index)
            $list = self::move($list, $indexToMove, $offset);
        } else if($offset > $indexToMove) {
            //Value will be moving down (will be changing to a higher value index)
            $list = self::move($list, $indexToMove, $offset - 1);
        } 
        return $list;
    }

    /* 
     * Moves the value at $list[$indexToMove] in between
     * $list[$offset - 1] and $list[$offset].
     */
    public static function move($list, $indexToMove, $offset)
    {
        $container = $list[$indexToMove];
        unset($list[$indexToMove]);
        $list = array_values($list);
        $list2 = array_slice($list, $offset);
        $list = array_slice($list, 0, $offset);
        array_push($list, $container);
        return array_merge($list, $list2);
    }

    //Swap the values of two array indices
    public static function swap($list, $indexA, $indexB)
    {
        $vA = $list[$indexA];
        $vB = $list[$indexB];
        $list[$indexA] = $vB;
        $list[$indexB] = $vA;
        return $list;
    }
}
```

Here are some example usages of the Rearranger class:

```
$a1 = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');

function display($list) { echo '<p>' . var_dump($list) . '</p>'; }

//Move value at index 4 to between index 0 and 1
$a1 = Rearranger::go($a1, 4, 1);
display($a1);

//Move value at index 1 to between index 3 and 4
$a1 = Rearranger::go($a1, 1, 4);
display($a1);

//Swap value 2 and 3    
$a1 = Rearranger::go($a1, 2, 3);
display($a1);

//Swap value 5 and 4 
$a1 = Rearranger::go($a1, 5, 4);
display($a1);

//Do nothing
$a1 = Rearranger::go($a1, 2, 2);
display($a1);
```

Comment: RearRanger sounds dirty to me ;)

Comment: Ah but the dirty is in your mind :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you mean is a sort algorithm right? Well there are loads of functions to sort arrays in [php](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php). Wich function you need depends on the exact requirements by witch you want to sort.

Alot of sort alghoritms have been devised over the years, take a [look](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).

**EDIT**
How about:

```
$source = array('a','b','c','d');
$head = array_splice($source,0,2);
$tail = array_splice($source,2,4);
$new = array_merge($head,array('e'),$tail);
// should yield array('a','b','e','c','d')
// Please check the array_splice documentation, iam not a 100% sure on the syntax.
```

This way you should be able to insert a new element into the array. Should help you on your way.

Comment: Well, I provided the exact requirements.

Answer (score 2):

```
$a1 = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
```

Inserting array element at index:

```
array_splice($array, 3, 0, 'Z'); 
print_r($a1);
```

> Array (
>       [0] => a
>       [1] => b
>       [2] => c
>       [3] => Z
>       [4] => d
>       [5] => e
>       [6] => f )

Swapping array elements:

```
list($a1[4], $a1[3]) = array($a1[3], $a1[4]);
print_r($a1);
```

> Array (
>       [0] => a
>       [1] => b
>       [2] => c
>       [3] => d
>       [4] => Z
>       [5] => e
>       [6] => f )

Comment: I tried using array_splice also, but it does not solve the problem of taking one value and inserting it between two other values (without overwriting anything). For example, taking $a1[3] and inserting it's value between $a1[4] and $a1[5]. Thanks for your response